# Create Error in Application Insights when Startup of ASP.NET Core 2.1 Application fails

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 REST Backend which works fine to track errors during normal execution.
However when i am having a problem during startup of the application (for example missing configurations), the process crashes and the exception ends up in IIs which displays a generic error page.

I found out i can control this behavior by setting the Environment Variable **ASPNETCORE_CAPTURESTARTUPERRORS** as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#capture-startup-errors) to get a detailed error page.

But i want this detailed error to be tracked in application insights and eventually control the availability setting of the application if such an error occurs.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 0416:** Adding the solution provided by op:

by wrapping `CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` in a `try/catch` block and sending the exception directly using `TelemetryClient`.

---

**Update:**

For ASP.NET core 2.1, it is possible(verified at my side, note: no need to use ILogger here, it can auto-collect the unhandled exceptions in program.cs or startup.cs). You can add the following code in the Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(
        builder =>
            {

            builder.AddApplicationInsights("ikey");    

            builder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                             (typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);    

            builder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                             (typeof(Startup).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
            }
        );
```

For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#capture-ilogger-logs-from-startupcs-and-programcs-in-aspnet-core-apps).

---

**Original answer:**

Unfortunately, `log errors during startup` is not supported.

Here is the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api), and it states:

There are a number of cases that the exception filters cannot handle. For example:

1.Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.

2.Exceptions thrown from message handlers.

3.Exceptions thrown during routing.

4.Exceptions thrown during response content serialization.

5.**Exception thrown during application start-up.**

6.Exception thrown in background tasks.

Comment: Not sure if this information is applicable to .NET Core Applications AS The linked article states: "This article is specifically focused on .NET Framework apps from a code example perspective. Some of the methods that work for .NET Framework are obsolete in the .NET Core SDK. Refer to the .NET Core SDK documentation if you have a .NET Core app."

Comment: @MarkusS. good point, I will check if it's available for .NET core and let you know the result.

Comment: @MarkusS. for asp.net core 2.1, please see the updated section in the answer.

Comment: Hi Ivan! Sorry for the delay. Your answer was helpful in a way as it was pointing me towards a right direction but unfortunately did not solve the issue. I could not see exceptions generated by ConfigureServices method in the Startup class (as this was the place where exceptions would occur when i was missing configuration values). However i was able to solve it by wrapping CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run(); in a try/catch block and sending the exception directly using TelemetryClient.

Comment: @MarkusS. Great! I did the same testing and worked. Anyway, I updated the answer by including your solution. If you don't mind, could you please accept it as answer?